# WPF custom control - where to check for specific parent

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I'm writing a `custom control` whereby it requires a specific parent for it to work.

In this case, its the Canvas panel. however where do i put the code to check that when it adds to the logical/visual tree, **`it throws a NotSupportedException`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) method in your custom control.

If you need a specific parent to work, I would advice creating a [custom items control](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/15/itemscontrol-a-is-for-abundance/) with a specific item container control and a specific items panel instead of forcing this behavior through an exception.